# How to get current div id when scrolling a content view page with Kendo UI for mobile or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-mobile

I'd like to get the id of the div displayed in the center of the screen.

Basically, the user can see several events in the app scrolling down or up. I have a map at the top of the screen and I'd like that For each event the user is currently viewing (so the div in the list is in the middle of the screen) I'd like to grab its id (or data attribute) to reposition the map properly with a js function.

The js function is fine, but I don't know how to get the Id of a div displayed at the center of the list (`data-role="content"`). If Kendo UI mobile doesn't provide such functionnality, is it doable with jQuery ?

EDIT:
I'd like to give more precision to my issue:
I'm looking to get the divs id, that are inside my div[data-role='content'], in a list. So in within my view and my content block, when scrolling through the divs (displayed like a list) I'd like to get the id of the div currently displayed in my content div(1 div is the side of the content div).

Comment: hmm I think I didn't make myself clear in the post, but there are several divs that are listed on the page and I need to know which one is currently displayed on the screen. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you need.

You can use the [view() method](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/application#methods-view) of the Application to retrieve the current View and the [contentElement() method](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/view#methods-contentElement) of the View to retrieve its content holder element (if you need it for DOM manipulation of its contents). If you need just the content element, you can use the [content property](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/view#fields-content). Something like that for the current Application:

```
var content = kendo.mobile.application.view().contentElement();
```

Comment: thanks, I'm not sure that's what I am looking for, I'm looking to get the divs id, that are inside my div[data-role='content'], in a list. So in within my view and my content block, when scrolling through the divs (displayed like a list) I'd like to get the id of the div currently displayed in my content div(1 div is the side of the content div).

Comment: I'm not sure I get the idea. Do you have a sample jsBin to show?